# How do you alternate positive and negative integers in set builder notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to rewrite this using set builder notation:

B = {−1, 1/2, −1/3, 1/4, −1/5, 1/6, · · · }

So far I can see its either alternating positive and negative integers to the power of -1. Or I could simply write it as 1/n where n is....

I can't work out how to express it.

Can anyone help?

would this work:

$n^{-1}$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and even

$n^{-1}$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z^-}$ and odd

Comment: Hint: $-1$ to the power of the denominator will give you the sign you’re after.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Negative 1 to any power is negative 1 isn't it?

Comment: @toby843 The product of an even number of negative numbers is positive, while the product of an odd number of negative numbers is negative.  For instance, $(-1)^1 = -1$, $(-1)^2 = 1$, $(-1)^3 = -1$, $(-1)^4 = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ok, I understand that. I'm still not sure I'm getting it in terms of set builder notation though. As far as I can set in this set I need to find a way to express -1^-1 then alternate to 2^-1, then -3^-1, then 4^-1 and so on....I am thinking something like: n^-1 | n is an element of Z+ and even, or n is an element of Z- and odd.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You have recognized that the $n$th term is $1/n$ when $n$ is an even positive integer and $1/n$ when $n$ is an odd negative integer.  However, we wish to index each term of the sequence with a positive integer.

Notice that
$$\frac{1}{-n} = -\frac{1}{n}$$
and that
$$(-1)^n = \begin{cases}
           1 & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
           -1 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
           \end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the $n$ term of the sequence is
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n} = \begin{cases}\\
                     \dfrac{1}{n} & \text{if $n$ is even}\\[2 mm]
                     -\dfrac{1}{n} & \text{if $n$ is odd}
                     \end{cases}
$$
for each positive integer $n$.